# Test that either one property contains value in AssertJ

Tags: assertj

Having following code:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TolkienCharacter{
    String nick;
    String name;
    String surname;
}


@Test
void go(){
    TolkienCharacter frodo = new TolkienCharacter("GoodFrodo", "Frodo", "Baggins");
    TolkienCharacter togo = new TolkienCharacter("Hobbit", "Togo", "Goodbody");
    List<TolkienCharacter> goodCharacters = Arrays.asList(frodo, togo);
```

I need to write assert, that checks that all elements in the goodCharacters list have nick or surname, which contains "good".

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be:

```java
assertThat(goodCharacters).extracting(TolkienCharacter::getNick, TolkienCharacter::getSurname)
    .allSatisfy(tuple -> assertThat(tuple.toList()).asInstanceOf(list(String.class))
        .anySatisfy(string -> assertThat(string).containsIgnoringCase("good")));
```

In case of failures, the error message would be like the following:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting all elements of:
  [("GoodFrodo", "Baggins"), ("Hobbit", "Badbody")]
to satisfy given requirements, but these elements did not:

("Hobbit", "Badbody")
error: 
Expecting any element of:
  ["Hobbit", "Badbody"]
to satisfy the given assertions requirements but none did:

"Hobbit"
error: 
Expecting actual:
  "Hobbit"
to contain:
  "good"
 (ignoring case)

"Badbody"
error: 
Expecting actual:
  "Badbody"
to contain:
  "good"
 (ignoring case)
```